# Form submitting but I don't know how or why?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've made a normal HTML form which when submitted, sends information to another page and that page processes the data and adds it to the database. But for some reason, if I refresh the 1st page which contains the form, an entry is being made into the database even though I can't see any reason for it to do so.

This is the code for the form:

```
<?php $owner = $_GET['user']; ?>

    <h2 class="dotted"><?php _e('Add feedback for user','appthemes'); echo " - ".$owner;?></h2>

        <form id='feedback' action='http://www.example.co.uk/add-feedback-response/?user=<?php echo $owner; ?>' method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <fieldset >

        <b>Your Username:</b> <?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?><br/><br/>

        <b>Rating: </b>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="positive" /> Positive
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="neutral" /> Neutral
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="negative" /> Negative<br/><br/>

        <label for='item' ><b>Item bought:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name='item' id='item' maxlength="500"/><br/><br/>

        <label for='comment' ><b>Comment:</b></label>
        <textarea name='comment' id='comment' maxlength="2500"></textarea><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit Feedback" />

        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for any help

Comment: when you are done processing the form, use header("location: ...") to redirect, this way there wont be double entries

Comment: You are taking input from `$_GET` and injecting it directly into the page? Hello XSS attacks.

Comment: when you refresh a page where you POSTed data these POST data will be resend

Comment: I will add some security for the potential attacks. I haven't submitted the form to be able to resend the data which is why it's confusing me. If I just browse to that page it automatically submits the form in the background without me pressing submit.

Comment: @Quentin: It doesn't matter if he does strip mess (XSS) after or before sending post ...

Comment: @genesis — The post is beside the point. The page displaying the form has a vulnerability.

Comment: XSS's classic vulnerability "alert(10);" doesn't hurt anyone ... only attacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you're trying to submit form again. Is browser alerting you that you're sending data again?

to restrict this, use

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

in proccessing form

Comment: Hi Genesis, the browser doesn't alert me that data is going to be resent - I've restarted my PC since and also cleared out firefox form history etc but it still does the same thing. If I open the page in Chrome, it works properly. I've added the header("Loca....code and that hasn't changed anything. Thanks,Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you refresh the form after it has submitted once, the form will be submitted again. (the browser would have warned you, "Are you sure you want to submit the page again" - didn't it?) Refresh is actually "repeat the last request".

If you think such a scenario is possible in your webapp, you will have to handle duplicate requests.